# Can you export thousands of objects in a blender scene to .obj format Individually (and automatically)

Tags: objects, export, groups

I have a model of a large city, where every house or cityblock is an object. I can manually pick each object and export them, but it is very tedious since there can be thousands of objects, and i would like to do this generally.

Does there exist such a tool in blender or anywhere else, that can take a large grouped scene and export the objects (Houses and the like) individually with some form of naming convention?

Thank you.

Comment: That question (Export every object into separate files) also has an answer with a bit of code to get you started.

Comment: Okay, i am new to Blender stackexchange, thanks for leading me in the right direction everyone. Much appreaciated! :)